# cannot add constraint to an existing table

Tags: mariadb, innodb, check-constraints, mariadb-10.4

i created a data base 'test' with table table 'user', inside the table there are 'id' and 'name' columns

`` CREATE TABLE `test`.`user` (`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `name` TEXT NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB; ``

now i want to add a constraint so no digits allowed in the 'name' and i don't know how to do it. i'm pretty sure i need to add `'name' NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'` but i just can't get it right

i tried `` ALTER TABLE `test`.`user` ADD CONSTRAINT no_digit_check CHECK ('name' NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'); `` but it gives me an error above 'CHECK' says `a new statement was found but no delimiter`

thanks

Comment: what does `select version();` show?  do you have a `;` at the end of the previous statement (or the proper delimiter if you've used the DELIMITER command)?

Comment: @ysth it says 10.4.24-MariaDB. i have a ```;``` in the end, and the delimiter is set to be the same

Comment: your alter table seems to be correct: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=15d354640cc4a6c35726ad7668d424e7  so the problem would seem to be in something before that

Comment: @ysth this is the only thing i did, created a table with the said command in the top and altered it with the next command

Comment: what client are you using?  I suspect whatever it is is trying to parse your sql and doesn't know about the newer syntax.

Comment: @ysth i am using exampp and phpmyadmin, as suggested by my teacher

Comment: I see sometimes upgrading phpmyadmin is recommended when you get this error; I don't know if it will help in this case.  If it doesn't, I suggest just using the mysql command line client.

Answer (score 0):

Use backtics, not apostrophes:

```
CHECK ( `name` ...)
```

instead of

```
CHECK ( 'name' ...)
```